# What does elementary function mean?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am looking at my double integration example problems and I see a note that says integral of $e^{-x^2}$ is not an elementary function. What does that mean? And why isn't that an elementary function?

It actually says observe integral of $e^{-x^2} dx$ is not an elementary function. But why is that? Same goes for integral of (sin(x)/x) dx, why isn't that an elementary function also?

Comment: Probably it should be the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) $\ \int e^{-x^2},\ $ not $\ ye^{-x^2}.\ $ The error function is often mentioned as an example of a nonelementary integral since the proof is relatively simple.

Comment: Ya, it actually says observe integral of $e^{-x^2} dx$ is not an elementary function. But why is that? Same goes for integral of (sin(x)/x) dx, why isn't that an elementary function also?

Answer (score 6):

The elementary functions form the smallest differential field that contains the complex constants and 
the variable $x$ and such that:

1. If $f' = g'/g$ where $g$ is elementary then $f$ is elementary (i.e. $\log(g)$ is elementary)
2. If $f' = g' f$ where $g$ is elementary then $f$ is elementary (i.e. $\exp(g)$ is elementary)
3. If $P(f) = 0$ where $P$ is a nonconstant polynomial with elementary coefficients then $f$ is elementary.

The theory of integration in elementary functions dates back to Liouville in 1833.

For more, see e.g. [this sci.math article](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/gIBp_QByjHQ/uE7P6wD_iEsJ)

Comment: -1 He is a student in multivariable calculus, your assuming way too much when you start talking about differential fields. This answer likely won't help him.

Comment: This answer was useful to me, though; I'd never known how elementary functions are given a precise definition.

Answer (score 2):

An elementary function is a function built from any combination of $+,-, \cdot, /$ and [function composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) with polynomial functions, exponential functions, logarithms, and the trigonometric functions of *one* variable.

It is very likely they meant to say the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

$$
\mathrm{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^x e^{-t^2}\ dx.
$$

The proof that this function is not elementary (the proof would essentially show that one *cannot* represent the integral as a finite amount of elementary functions) is quite involved. The author of the book is likely trying to demonstrate the integration of an elementary function ($e^{-t^2}$ *is* elementary) does not necessarily yield and elementary function as the result. One more time,

$e^{-t^2}$ *is* elementary but $\int e^{-t^2}$ *is not* elementary.

Comment: Ya, it actually says observe integral of $e^{-x^2} dx$ is not an elementary function. But why is that? Same goes for integral of (sin(x)/x) dx, why isn't that an elementary function also?

Comment: Check my edit, I added some information.

Comment: Roots of polynomials are also elementary.