# Integrating $\int (t+t^2)^\frac{1}{3}\,dt$

Tags: integration

*Question:* Find the integral below$$\int (t+t^2)^\frac {1}{3}\,\mathrm dt$$

---

I have tried to use the standard methods such as "by part" to solve this integral, only to end up in an algebraic mess.

> *Can someone suggest a method that would suffice in solving this and/or otherwise post their worked solution.*

Comment: it might not be possible to find a known function whose derivative is your integrand .

Comment: I'd try a change of variables with $x=t-\frac12$. To integrate $\left(x^2 -\frac14\right)^{1/3}$ I'd do a trig substitution; you might need to use the tangent of half-angle trick.

Comment: It looks like it does not have an elementary primitive, according to [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28t%2Bt%5E2%29%5E%281%2F3%29)

Comment: Do hypergeometric functions count (LOL)?

Comment: @MarkFischler If I invent a name for this function $f(x)=\int_0^x (t+t^2)^{\frac{1}{3}} dt$, does it also count? (LOL LOL)

Comment: Do you have bounds?

Comment: @Miguel Haha, no. The difference between hypergeometric functions and yours is simple: Is there any motivation to have hypergeometric functions for *other* purposes? Is there any motivation to have your "function" for any other purposes other than this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to think this integral is an [elementary function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362024/442).

Maple evaluates it in terms of a hypergeometric function
$$
\int \!\sqrt [3]{{t}^{2}+t}\;{\rm d}t=\frac{3}{4}\,{t}^{4/3}\;
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}\left(-\frac{1}{3},\frac{4}{3};\,\frac{7}{3};\,-t\right)}
$$