# How can one formalize elementary-ness?

Tags: reference-request, differential-algebra

I'm trying to decipher what general principals generalize all elementary functions.

Does the following hold?:

All elementary functions $y = f(x)$ are a solution an equation of the form $P(x,e^x,\ln(x),y) = Q(x,e^x,\ln(x))$?

Because if you have just $x,$ you have all algebraic equations to start with encapsulated as being solutions to $P(y) = Q(x).$

Comment: Elementary functions also allow compositions of things like this, as well as trigonometric functions, don't they?

Comment: I'm less sure of composition in the general case. I'm just trying to figure out what generalizes the concept of elementary-ness. The thing is, not all solutions to such an equation are elementary, so I'm not sure if I have it right. I think though, the statement is closer to correct at least for algebraic functions, though I don't remember the theorem.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question. The definition of an elementary function from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function "a function of a single variable (typically real or complex) that is defined as taking sums, products, and compositions of finitely many polynomial, rational, trigonometric, hyperbolic, and exponential functions, including possibly their inverse functions". What do you mean exactly by generalizing the concept of elementary-ness?

Comment: Perhaps one up to the extent that elementary functions form a field.

Comment: I don't know if this makes sense, but perhaps the most minimal subfield of which all other possible elementary functions can also be comprised, perhaps those are the ones of the equation I present.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361969/what-does-elementary-function-mean and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118113/what-makes-elementary-functions-elementary and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358050/what-constitutes-the-classification-of-functions-into-elementary-and-non-e and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628414/is-there-anything-special-about-elementary-functions and probably many others.

Comment: Did those links help?

Comment: Not quite. The first link did, but I wish there was a less clunky definition than saying "algebraic functions, logarithms and exponentials over a complex field".

Comment: Well, there's more where those came from. If you just type *elementary functions* into the search box on this page, many older (and possibly helpful) questions will turn up.